# Cant get outputbox to display message

Tags: javascript, html, output

I'm trying to make a website that allows you to calculate grade but I am not able to get it to spit out the final variable into the output box, I've tried over an hour now and cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>grade</title>

  <link href="../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Grade() {
      var homework_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('homework').value);
      var lab_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lab').value);
      var midterm1_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('midterm1').value);
      var midterm2_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('midterm2').value);
      var finalexam_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalexam').value);
      var project_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('project').value);
      var attendance_grade = parseFloat(document.getElementById('attendance').value);
      var midterm_total = midterm1_grade + midterm2_grade / 2;
      var course_grade = homework_grade * 0.15 + lab_grade * 0.20 + midterm_total * 0.20 + finalexam_grade * 0.10 + project_grade * 0.30 + attendance_grade * 0.05;

      document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = course_grade;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Grade Calculator</h1>

  <p>Enter your average homework grade: <input type="numeric" id="homework" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your average lab grade: <input type="numeric" id="lab" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your first midterm grade: <input type="numeric" id="midterm1" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your second midterm grade: <input type="numeric" id="midterm2" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your final exam grade: <input type="numeric" id="finalexam" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your project grade: <input type="numeric" id="project" size="10" value="" /></p>
  <p>Enter your attendance grade: <input type="numeric" id="attendance" size="10" value="" /></p>

  <p><button value="Calculate Grade" onlclick="Grade();"> Calculate Grade </button></p>

  <p> Grade:
    <div class="OutputBox" type="text" id="outputDiv"> Output Message </div>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, change `onlclick` to `onclick`.

To help debugging, you can add a `console.log("function called");` to the beginning of your function and open your browser's console to see if your function is called. It will print the message `function called` but you can also print your variables value.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo within the "Calculate Grade" button. Change `onlclick`  to `onclick`, for example:

```
<button value="Calculate Grade" onclick="Grade();"> Calculate Grade </button>
```